# why does my Mac keep crashing?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, kernel

(I will have to do this fast, since I think my mac will crash again.)

My Mac keeps crashing. It started happening since I installed Adobe Acrobat Pro (since then I have removed it), but it might be unrelated to that. Even after I removed it, it still keeps crashing every few minutes.

Here is the latest panic log from Console:

```
Sun Jun 15 22:44:53 2014
Machine-check capabilities (cpu 7) 0x0000000000000c09:
 family: 6 model: 42 stepping: 7 microcode: 26
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2675QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
 9 error-reporting banks
 threshold-based error status present
 extended corrected memory error handling present
Machine-check status 0x0000000000000004:
 machine-check in progress
MCA error-reporting registers:
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC1_STATUS(0x405): 0x0980000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC2_STATUS(0x409): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe00000000800400 valid
  MCA error code:            0x0400
  Model specific error code: 0x0080
  Other information:         0x00000000
  Threshold-based status:    Undefined
  Status bits:
   Processor context corrupt
   ADDR register valid
   MISC register valid
   Error enabled
   Uncorrected error
   Error overflow
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e): 0x00003f7f817522f5
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f): 0x000000000003ffff
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC5_STATUS(0x415): 0x0020000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC6_STATUS(0x419): 0x0020000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC7_STATUS(0x41d): 0x0020000000000000 invalid
 Package 0 logged:
 IA32_MC8_STATUS(0x421): 0x0020000000000000 invalid
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80002c4dd5): "Machine Check at 0xffffff7f81dd9c7f, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007f809bc00000, CR3: 0x0000000000100000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000031, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff80e842bd80, RBP: 0xffffff80e842bdb0, RSI: 0x0000000000000007, RDI: 0xffffff8011ea2400\n" "R8:  0xffffff8011d5a800, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x8000000000100000, R11: 0xffffff80002dad00\n" "R12: 0x00000000000008f8, R13: 0xffffff8011c29940, R14: 0xffffff8011d5a800, R15: 0x0000000000000007\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff7f81dd9c7f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1699.32.7/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:278
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80e84bcec0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80e84bcf40 : 0xffffff80002c4dd5 
0xffffff80e84bd0a0 : 0xffffff80002daf2f 
0xffffff80e842bdb0 : 0xffffff7f81dc7f65 
0xffffff80e842be80 : 0xffffff7f81dc9a5c 
0xffffff80e842bf30 : 0xffffff80002c6422 
0xffffff80e842bf50 : 0xffffff800022d375 
0xffffff80e842bf90 : 0xffffff800022ccdb 
0xffffff80e842bfb0 : 0xffffff8000820057 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(195.0)[70D39B65-894A-335D-A051-0C8B8CAFEA82]@0xffffff7f81dc6000->0xffffff7f81deefff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 106689630414
last loaded kext at 46405102669: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7f81df0000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.openafs.filesystems.afs 1.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000    7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   561.7.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller    7.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
```

Comment: What's the battery status? Is it overheating? This sounds like a heat issue to me.

Answer (score 3):

A machine-check exception is typically a hardware failure. If you're lucky, it's "just" a RAM failure and if you're super lucky, you can fix it by re-seating your RAM, or (lucky, but not super lucky) replacing a failing RAM card. If you're unlucky, it could be a motherboard problem.

On another Mac, create a bootable external drive (USB, FireWire, or Thunderbolt) with a clean install of a version of Mac OS X that you know your failing Mac supports, then plug that drive into the failing Mac and boot from that. If you still get the machine-check exception, you're probably seeing a hardware failure.